# facebook share button is not showing the image

Tags: facebook-share

I am currently creating a  facebook app and I need to create a facebook share button.I used facebook share button social plugin and setup the meta tags.[image with meta tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3iD7.png)

my app genarating images using app users facebook id.I am using a session to get the app id to my page.
It's working fine in image src tag.but not in og:image.
[img src image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT7rO.png)

I used sharing debugger it's only reading the url untill the "http://www.koombiyocharacter.me/joined_images/joined_image" but not variable i got from session.[not with the session variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iut75.png)
I need to share with the image.now it shares without the image.Can I find a solution for this with php sdk?.[Shares like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQNK8.png)
How Can I solve this problem.I am new to facebook app development.

Comment: Try testing your site here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: I tested it.But not showing the image.

Comment: Ok.I found the answer.thanks